# Where should i put the break point in chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm pretty new to chrome developer tools and i notice when i put in a break point and refresh the page that sometimes the page pauses at the break point and sometimes it doesn't. Does the break point have to be within a function or outside of a function in order for it to application to pause at the break point? Im trying to check and see if some values are defined or undefined..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `breakpoint` tells the debugger to stop when execution reaches the statement with said `breakpoint` and can be placed on any [`statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

> Does the break point have to be within a function or outside of a function in order for it to application to pause at the break point?

Depends on what you want to *debug*. If you want execution to stop when the page reaches the `function` *definition*, then set a `breakpoint` on the *"outside"*. If though, you want to break when the function is called, set it somewhere *"inside"* the definition of the `function`.

Answer (score 0):

The breakpoints should work fine pretty much anywhere, so long as the code is stepping through.

If you're having serious issues, you can consider using the non-standard `debugger` keyword. That will almost emulate the functionality of breakpoints, apart from you're setting them in your actual code rather than the developer tools.

For example:

```
function test(y) {
    debugger;

    var x = y;
}
```

*(As with all developer-focused JavaScript features (ie. `console.log`), don't forget to remove from production code)*